# Почему языки C-семейства заняли свое "особое" место среди прочих языков программирования

Tags: c

А как вы считаете почему языки C-семейства заняли свое "особое" место среди прочих языков программирования?

Comment: Просто они *офигительно круты*.

Comment: Когда-то давно видел в интернете шутливое сопоставление между языками программирования и философами. Язык C в нём был сопоставлен Декарту. Собственно говоря, это и есть ответ на вопрос. Влияние языка C на индустрию более-менее равнозначно влиянию Декарта на философию.

Comment: Написал ответ основанный на различиях в нотации между `Lisp C и Forth`, а вопрос в это время закрыли. Целый килобайт полезного текста пропал из-за некомпетентных(C это действительно особенный ЯП, он выстрелили не просто так, тема далеко не холиварна и вопрос хороший) голосов за закрытие.  Хотя что теперь поделать, читайте неплохую историческую версию @Vlad и радуйтесь жизни.

Comment: @igumnov: Но хоть текст остался в буфере?

Comment: @VladD Да конечно. Суть моего ответа в том что `C` является первым четким и ясным императивным ЯВУ с нотацией `a+b`, которая понятна большинству людей, в отличии от конкурирующей Lispовой `+ a b` и Forthовой `a b +`, появившихся примерно в то же время 45-50 лет назад. (Конечно такие способы записи выражений были известны и раньше, но в явный оборот они видимо попали именно в те времена)

Comment: @igumnov, так просто переоткройте и добавьте свой ответ. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: @igumnov Это, кстати, важный аспект популярности. Ещё, я думаю, фигурные скобки повлияли. Они очень милые. В питоне мне их очень не хватает. Не настолько, чтобы его не использовать, но тем не менее.

Comment: @igumnov: Проголосовал за переоткрытие. Мы ещё недостаточно устоявшийся сайт для снобизма.

Comment: @Shamov Да да фигурные скобочки `{{}{}{}{}{}}`это тоже важно, еще фирменный инкремент-декремент, составные присваивания. `a+=a++ + --a;` и указатели `int *(*f)(char *с)`. Веселее же чем Lisp с его унылыми эзотерическими пугающими людей **круглыми** скобками `(+ (* 3 (+ (* 2 4) (+ 3 5))) (+ (- 10 7) 6))`

Comment: @igumnov Указатели и в Паскале были :)

Comment: Вопросы опросники запрещены в сообществе. Перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначный ответ.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Думаю, они «взлетели» на феноменальном успехе самого языка C.

Язык C был успешен потому, что во время его разработки была нужда в хорошем низкоуровневом системном языке. C оказался самым популярным среди них не в последнюю очередь потому, что семейство UNIX-подобных операционных систем выбрало C в качестве системного языка. (Что неудивительно, учитывая участие Денниса Ритчи в обоих проектах.)

*Высокоуровневых* языков было достаточно в те далёкие времена (LISP, COBOL, Basic), но компиляторы того времени не были способны адекватно оптимизировать высокоуровневый код. C же снискал славу «кроссплатформенного ассемблера»: код на нём можно было легко оптимизировать вручную.

Затем, C++ был пожалуй первым *хорошим* (для своего времени) языком программирования, ориентированным на практическое программирование. Совместимостью с C он обязан как своему взлёту и популярности, так и многим неустранимым своим недостаткам.

Далее, вступает MS-DOS. Программисты Microsoft вдохновлялись UNIX-системами, и решили выбрать C как системный язык. Далее, долгое время de facto-стандартом для написания оконных систем под Windows стал, естественно, C++, как подходящий последователь C.

Таким образом, две популярные платформы (UNIX и DOS/indows) приветствовали знание C и его потомков, что конечно же привело к их широкому распространению.

---

Тем не менее, и у других языков был шанс. Например, более высокоуровневый Pascal был очень популярен в среде разработчиков под DOS, и планировался вначале как системный язык Windows. И он, кажется, был языком выбора под платформой Macintosh. (До тех пор, пока там предпочтительным языком не стал Objective C — снова язык из семейства C.) Pascal вплоне мог перехватить лидирующую роль в семействе языков практического программирования. Но, к сожалению, язык не развивался адекватно нуждам программистов, и был в основном вытеснен своими коллегами, основанными на синтаксисе C.

---

Стоит заметить, однако, что последователи C, унаследовав *синтаксис* C, вовсе не унаследовали его *стиль* и *философию*.

Comment: Не соглашусь только с тем, что взлёт С++ был быстрым. Страуструп пилит его с 1979 года. Первый же стандарт появился в 1998 (19 лет спустя).

Comment: @Shamov: Хм. Пожалуй. Мне кажется, он сначала был никому не нужен, а вот как только понадобилось делать сложные оконные системы, реально взлетел. Впрочем, может быть, я ошибаюсь.

Comment: Я не думаю, что оконные системы имели к его взлёту настолько прямое отношение. Он взлетел, когда появился STL и все его освоили. Возможно оконные системы имели к этому косвенное отношение, но не более того. Любую большую работу делать приятнее, когда половину этой любой работы уже кто-то сделал. А работу по разработке сложных оконных систем никак нельзя назвать маленькой.

Comment: @Shamov: Мне кажется, оконные системы начали требовать от программ (и программистов) той сложности, при которой уже необходимо адекватное простое средство инкапсуляции и абстракции. Далее, с появлением оконных систем программы вышли из академического и промышленного круга задач, и пришлось писать программы для «обыкновенного» пользователя, который требовал «интуитивного» поведения (никому не хочется читать мануалы!), а значит, и сложной бизнес-логики. Всё это привело к взлетевшему спросу на ООП.

Comment: @Shamov: Smalltalk вроде бы и появился под разработку оконной системы, ЕМНИП.

Comment: Версия о том, что спрос на оконные системы повлиял на рост популярности С++, не объясняет того, почему популярным стал С++, а не Objective-C, который для этой цели подходит значительно лучше.

Comment: @Shamov: Это да. Но _оба_ языка — последователи C. Думаю, не последнюю роль тут сыграл более привычный синтаксис и более C-образная семантика (вызов метода = вызов функции, а вот отправление сообщения — что-то совсем другое). Возможно, тут ещё сыграло Win vs. Mac? В любом случае, _оба_ языка добавили в копилку группы C-образных языков.

Comment: Win vs. Mac - вряд ли повлияло, поскольку это просто переносит необъяснённость выбора на другой уровень: почему для Win были выбраны именно плюсы? А вот привычный синтаксис и семантика - это реальный аргумент. Очень может быть, что они сыграли важную роль. Скажем так, не меньшую, чем STL.

Comment: @Shamov: Плюсы vs ObjC под Win: случайность? (тоже фактор!) вкусы конкретного архитектора? производительность (насильно виртуальные методы в ObjC) под слабые процессоры?

Comment: А зачем в оконной системе предельная производительность? Уже само то, что ты её используешь, как бы говорит, что тебе пофиг...

Comment: Пресловутое "Сколько бы Энди не выдал, Билл заберет всё" не на пустом месте возникло. Очевидно, Билл не парился насчёт производительности.

Comment: @Shamov: Ну уж вам. Вон я недавно как раз приводил цитату из Рэймонда Чена, почему в WinMain нету `char* argv[]`. Ответ: чтобы сэкономить 2кб на парсер комстроки. То есть, о низкоуровневых штуках думали. Иначе не выиграли бы гонку на десктопе.

Comment: Это какой-то притянутый за уши ответ. Скорее всего подлинная причина в том, что в винде комстрока вообще почти не используется. На ненужную вещь и одного байта жалко... не то что 2кб.

Comment: @Shamov: ну, это вы Реймонду лучше скажите, я лишь повторил его мнение. Вот само обсуждение: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/03/6644060.aspx

Comment: Оставим Реймонда в покое. Честно говоря, я даже не знаю, кто это такой.

Comment: @Shamov: Это один из ведущих разработчиков Microsoft, в своё время был ответственным за обратную совместимость. Как написал Джефф Этвуд (один из соучередителей Stackoverflow), "Raymond Chen fixed more Windows bugs than you've had hot dinners". И это скорее всего правда.

Answer (score 6):

Вообще @Vlad довольно хорошо изложил с исторической точки зрения, но я зайду с другой стороны, грамматической/синтаксической.

Любой не эзотерический язык программирования это так или иначе выбор между:

`Lisp C Forth`.

Функциональной, императивной, конкатенативной(стэковой) парадигмой:

Префиксной `+ a b`, инфиксной `a + b`, постфиксной `a b +`  записью выражений.

Так вот *C*(и остальные языки семейства, последовавшие за ним позднее) просто стал одним из первых общеупотребительных языков, который практически идеально и без лишнего синтаксического сахара вписывается в императивную парадигму.

Он просто является её прямым и логичным выражением. Запись `a + b` выглядит понятнее для большинства людей, чем конкурирующие *Lispовое* `+ a b` и *Forthовое* `a b +`. (Конечно все эти 3 нотации были известны еще задолго до изобретения *Lisp* *C* и *Forth*, но в общее употребление они вошли похоже именно в те времена)

Кроме того он достаточно прост, в нем по мимо обычного потока управления есть всего 6 основных средств построения абстракций: указатели, функции, структуры, указатели на функции, препроцессор и `typedef`.

Остальные элементы вроде фигурных скобок:

`{{}{}{}{}{}}`

Составных присваиваний:

`a+=a++ + --a;`

Указателей:

`int *(*f)(char *с)`

Смотрятся просто веселее и читаются легче чем *Lisp* с его унылыми эзотерическими пугающими людей круглыми скобками:

`(+ (* 3 (+ (* 2 4) (+ 3 5))) (+ (- 10 7) 6))`

или *Forth* с Йоды магистра речью умной:

`: FLOOR5 ( n -- n' )   DUP 6 < IF DROP 5 ELSE 1 - THEN ;`.

Что касается других старых императивных языков вроде *Pascal*, *BASIC*, *Fortran*, то в них просто слишком много сахара и они все же не так изящны и выразительны как *C*.

Можно например чисто визуально сравнить 4 Hello World для весьма похожих языков *Pascal*, *Visual Basic*, *Fortran* и *С*. Что вы выберете?

```
Program HelloWord;
begin
     writeLn ('Hello World!')
end.

Module Hello
  Sub Main()
      MsgBox("Hello, World!")
  End Sub
End Module

Program Hello
   Print *, "Hello World!"
End Program Hello

#include<stdio.h>
main() {
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

P.S. Конечно в обычном *BASIC* можно сделать так `? "Hello, World!"`, но ничто ведь не мешает Вам: `#define $ printf`

Comment: Я тоже всё время забываю `\n` в конце `printf` :)

Comment: Да они все четыре написаны через CTRL+C и CTRL +V. Там и запятых с восклицательными знаками не хватает. Лень. P.S. Копипаста как обычно только множит баги.

Comment: Quick Basic: `PRINT "Hello World!"` :-) Эх, помнится, на нём умудрялся писать обработку гауссовских распределений и рисовать их графики аж в VGA-режиме... Но появившийся как раз в то время борландс 3.0 быстро перетянул одеяло на себя :-)

Answer (score 3):

Помнится, для меня с коллегами Си в середине 80-х стал просто светом в окошке из-за своего лаконизма, прозрачности  и отсутствию (по сравнению с Паскалем)  дурацких ограничений, которые почему-то считаются авторами языков просто обязательными для программирования без ошибок.

Comment: Сразу вспоминается шутка про Денниса Ритчи, где он якобы говорит: "Мы  остановились, добившись успешной компиляции следующего кода: `for(;P("\n"),R-;P("|"))for(e=C;e-;P("_"+(*u++/8)%2))P("| "+(*u/4)%2);`"

Comment: @Shamov `;e-;`?

Comment: @Athari Х/з... я плохо знаю Си.

Comment: [e--, конечно же](http://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/unix-hoax.html)

Answer (score 1):

Началось все, скорее всего, именно с синтаксиса. Из низкоуровневых языков, компилировавшихся в оптимальный код, C для своего времени был самым удобным.

Замена всевозможных длиннющих `BEGIN` и `END` на `{` и `}` (и т.д.) сыграла немаловажную роль. Это сейчас у нас IDE с autocomplete и прочими ништяками, а тогда сокращение количества букаф в программах было для многих великой радостью. Этим и другими плюсами к себе завоевал расположение C.